# Ajax não funciona quando vem de um select do formulário

Tags: jquery, ajax

Quando o  **#sectionChooser** vem do Ajax o  não funciona o select **#bairros** para colocar a #rua, onde estaria o problema?

Html

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="Planos">Planos</label>

              <select name="Planos" id="sectionChooser" class="form-control valid" aria-invalid="false">              

              <option value="">Selecione</option>                   
    <option value="1">Diamante</option><option value="2">Ouro</option><option value="3">Prata</option><option value="4">Light</option><option value="5">Free</option><option value="19">Link</option>                   
              </select>         

    <div class="panel" id="1" style="display: block;">    

    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label><b>Diamante</b></label>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="Bairro">Bairro</label>
                        <select class="form-control valid" name="bairro" id="bairro3" required="" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>                 
<option value="1">teste bairro</option><option value="2">teste bairro 2 3</option><option value="3">ação bairros</option><option value="4">Centro</option>


    </select> 
                    </div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="Rua">Rua</label>



<select class="form-control" name="rua" id="rua" required="">





    </select> 




                    </div>
```

estou tentando assim, mais ainda não deu

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){
        var myID = $(this).val();
        $('.panel').each(function(){
            myID === $(this).attr('id') ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
            console.log("ok");
        });
    })


    $(document).on('change', '#bairro', function(){
        var bairroID = $(this).val();

        if(bairroID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax_data2.php',
                data:'bairro_id='+bairroID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#rua').html(html);
                    console.log("ok");
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#rua').html('<option value="">Select categoria first</option>');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Esse #sectionChooser vem do Ajax?

Comment: sim vem do ajax, ainda nao deu certo

Comment: Passe seu html também para que possamos simular seu problema.

Comment: coloquei na resposta

Comment: Não vá alterando a pergunta conforme as respostas. Senão a gente perde como estava.

Comment: Onde tem `elemento` é apenas um exemplo... no lugar de `elemento` vc coloca o seletor... veja a resposta.

Comment: vc não precisa alterar nada no seu código, apenas os dois eventos que coloquei na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que está selecionando o `id` errado: em vez de `#bairro`, o correto seria `#bairro3`, veja:

```
                                                  id correto
                                                       ↓
<select class="form-control valid" name="bairro" id="bairro3" required="" aria-invalid="false">
```

Ao usar Ajax, em vez de usar eventos `.change`, use `.on`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){
```

e

```
$(document).on('change', '#bairro', function(){
```

Assim não terá problemas de delegação com elementos inseridos de forma dinâmica na página.

O código deve ficar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){
        var myID = $(this).val();
        $('.panel').each(function(){
            myID === $(this).attr('id') ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
    })


    $(document).on('change', '#bairro3', function(){
        var bairroID = $(this).val();

        if(bairroID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax_data2.php',
                data:'bairro_id='+bairroID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#rua').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#rua').html('<option value="">Select categoria first</option>');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: ainda não deu certo amigo, estranho que não retorna nenhum erro no console

Comment: coloque um `console.log("ok");` dentro dos eventos para ver se pelo menos está pegando o click.

Comment: aqui sim  $(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){ mais aqui   $(document).on('change', '#bairro', function(){ nao

Comment: olha a minha pergunta q editei com os console.log("ok");

Comment: Coloque logo após a abertura do evento para ver se o click é escutado, e não lá no meio.

Comment: fiz assim $(document).on('change', '#bairro', function(){
  console.log("ok"); e não retornou nada ainda, apenas no $(document).on('change', '#sectionChooser', function(){  retorna "ok"

Comment: arrumei o html na  pergunta e coloquei os bairros  e rua

Comment: O problema é que o id é `#bairro3` e não `#bairro`

Comment: hmm entendi, vou ver o que faço, obrigado

Comment: Mas ele deveria pegar o id Bairro3 aqui $(document).on('change', '#bairro', function(){
        var bairroID = $(this).val(); mas mesmo assim nao funciona

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77229/discussion-between-wagner-martins-bodyboard-and-dvd).

Answer (score -1):

Para pegar a `<option>` selecionada:

```
$('#sectionChooser option:selected').val();
```

Comment: ainda não deu certo amigo

Comment: Então o erro não está ai, porque assim vc pega o option selecionado, pode dar um alert pra vc ver o value.

Comment: oha como eu fiz na resposta, coloquei o html também